# ggplot for two columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have these two columns ie fruit and freq in my dataframe.I am trying to plot a histogram or bar graph such that my x axis has fruit,and y has the freq.My table is like this.

```
fruit   freq
apple   5
orange  0
banana  3
grapes  10
```

I am a beginner and not able to figure out this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

```
# Define the data
myData = data.frame("fruit" = c("apple", "orange", "banana", "grapes"), "freq" = c(5, 0, 3, 10))
# Load library
library(ggplot2)
# Call plot function
ggplot(data = myData, aes(x = fruit, y = freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

We call the ggplot() function to create a base/empty plot layer. Within this function, we tell ggplot what our data is, as well as tell it the mapping to the 'x' and to the 'y'. Your 'x' is fruit, and 'y' is freq. We add the bar plot to it afterward by calling `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. We use `stat = "identity"` here since we already have counts for each fruit. More information is given here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know the title refers explicitly to `ggplot`, but if you're after something simple, with your data in a `data.frame` `f`

```
barplot(f$freq, names.arg=f$fruit)
```

[image]